# Prove $\frac{a(b+c)}{b^2+bc+c^2} \geqslant \frac{8a^2+2a(b+c)-(b-c)^2}{3(a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca)}.$

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, sum-of-squares-method, buffalo-way

Let $a,\,b,\,c$ are non-negative such that $ab+bc+ca>0.$ Prove that
$$\frac{a(b+c)}{b^2+bc+c^2} \geqslant \frac{8a^2+2a(b+c)-(b-c)^2}{3(a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca)}. \quad (1)$$
**Note.** Because
$$\sum \frac{8a^2+2a(b+c)-(b-c)^2}{3(a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca)} = 2.$$
So, from $(1)$ we get know [inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h24555p156212) of [Darij Grinberg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/586/darij-grinberg) 
$$\frac{a(b+c)}{b^2+bc+c^2}+\frac{b(c+a)}{c^2+ca+a^2}+\frac{c(a+b)}{a^2+ab+b^2} \geqslant 2.$$
My proof use sum of squares method.

Comment: So you've shown the sum of three terms is greater than the sum of three others.. .that might not imply each term is bigger than the other?

Comment: @Nguyenhuyen_AG It's obvious that the Darij's inequality is a linear inequality of $w^3$ and $uvw$ kills it immediately.

Comment: @Dhanvi Sreenivasan You can find counterexamples?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg There are many ways to prove it, $ uvw $ is the fastest =))

Comment: Take 3,4,1 and 2,2,2. 3+4+1 > 2+2+2, but 1 < 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BW helps!

We need to prove that:
$$3(b+c)a^3-(5b^2+2bc+5c^2)a^2+(b+c)(b^2+bc+c^2)a+(b-c)^2(b^2+bc+c^2)\geq0.$$

Thus, since our inequality is symmetric respect to $b$ and $c$, we have two cases only:

1. $a=\min\{a,b,c\}$, $b=a+u$ and $c=a+v$.

Thus, $u\geq0$, $v\geq0$ and we need to prove that:
$$3(u^2+v^2)a^2+(u+v)(4u^2-5uv+4v^2)a+(u-v)^2(u^2+uv+v^2)\geq0,$$ which is obvious;

2. $b=\min\{a,b,c\}$, $a=b+u$ and $c=b+v$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$3(2u^2-2uv+v^2)b^2+(6u^3-3u^2v-5uv^2+4v^2)b+v(3u+v)(u-v)^2\geq0,$$ which is obvious again.

Comment: I think BW is the simple way to prove without computer!

Answer (score 2):

Thank @Michael Rozenberg :D We write inequality as
$$f(a) = 3(b+c)a^3-(5b^2+2bc+5c^2)a^2+(b+c)(b^2+bc+c^2)a+(b^2+bc+c^2)(b-c)^2 \geqslant 0.$$
But
$$\left(a+\frac{7b+7c}{4}\right) \cdot f(a)=\frac{3}{4}(b+c)(2a^2-b^2-c^2-ab+2bc-ca)^2+\frac{5bc(b+c)(b-c)^2}{4}$$
$$+\frac{17abc[(a-b)^2+(a-c)^2]}{4}+\frac{25a(b^2+c^2-ab-ca)^2}{8}+\left(\frac{a}{8}+b+c\right)(b-c)^2(b+c-a)^2.$$
So $f(a) \geqslant 0.$

Comment: Nice! +1. But it's very hard to find this solution without computer. By the way, my solution is by hand.

Comment: Yes. So I posted here to find a simple solution =))

Comment: What is your idea to get it?

Comment: @Nguyenhuyen_AG   I saw you obtained simple SOS often (I will get complicated SOS usually). If you use some solvers to get the SOS, how powerful are your solvers? Did you try harder SOS problems?

Comment: @RiverLi It's not strong, many problems can not find SOS. Ji Chen SOS or szl6208 SOS is better than

Comment: @Nguyenhuyen_AG Thanks. Hope to see more SOS challenge problems in MSE.

Comment: May I know this program?

Answer (score 1):

We have$:$
$$48\, \left( b+c \right) ^{2} \left( {b}^{2}+bc+{c}^{2} \right) 
 \left( {a}^{2}+ab+ac+{b}^{2}+bc+{c}^{2} \right) 
\cdot (\text{LHS}-\text{RHS})$$
$$=48\,a ( b+c )  \Big[b^2+c^2-a(b+c)\Big] ^{2}+4\,(b-c)^2 \Big[ 2\, a(b+c)-(2b^2+bc+2c^2) \Big] ^{2}$$

$$+4\,bc \left( 8\,{b}^{2}+7\,bc+8\,{c}^{2} \right)  \left( b-c \right) ^
{2} \geqq 0.$$

Comment: Simple SOS solutions are beautiful.

Comment: @RiverLi Thank you, I really hope to see your program to help you SOS.

Comment: I found that the equality cases are important. If an inequality holds with equality at only one point, sometimes it is not so difficult. If an inequality holds with equality at multiple points (even many points), it is often difficult.

Comment: @RiverLi I agree. And you can SOS for almost inequality, huh?

Comment: No. I can't.  It is too difficult.

Comment: @RiverLi What program you use to get SOS? I use Maple but I can only use it to factor the expression and get equality from two expression.

Comment: Sorry, I know little about SOS. You may search the internet.